# Fast cipher suite

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, debian

Hello i using websocket over TLS but now the requests are slow
Its possible to use strong cipher suite (compatible IE6/XP) for https:// and faster cipher for wss:// ? like

```
server {
 location / {
   ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHEE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA"
 }

  location /websocket/ {
   ...
   another cipher suite
  }
}
```

I using nginx 1.8, debian 7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a Websocket is just a layer inside an established HTTP(S) tunnel you cannot have different ciphers for normal HTTPS and WSS to the same host.

Comment: Thanks Steffen; you suggest me what cipher suite for a good performance with HTTPS and WSS ?

Comment: @soooo: it depends on hardware platform (i.e. is AES-NI available), programming language (can it use AES-NI), where the performance problem is (client or server) etc. You might have a look what other heavy SSL users do, like [cloudflare](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200933580-What-cipher-suites-does-CloudFlare-use-for-SSL-). For nginx on PC AES-GCM is probably very fast but if you have a mobile client [better use ChaCha20](https://blog.cloudflare.com/do-the-chacha-better-mobile-performance-with-cryptography/).